# Crystal Reports not working in IE 11

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, crystal-reports

We have just upgraded our IE browsers from version 10 to 11.
And we are not able to fetch crystal reports. When we change the compatibility mode to previous version 
then it works.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: I had many troubles when upgraded ti IE 11, involving Crystal Reports and many other elements in my website. After installing Aspnet 4.5 on the server problems solved automatically. Can you try?

Comment: Yes even i had lots of problems when i upgraded to IE11 other than this issue and it solved by upgrading framework to 4.5. But above issue is still there even after upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up the compatibility header mode on the page or the iframe to force it to run on ie7 or ie5, depending the version of crystal that u use, this worked for me:

or with jquery

$("head, #iframecrystal").append('');

if u have a frame named iframecrystal in the page